# random data matrix

Tags: r

How to randomize values in an R matrix

For example, here is what I Would like to randomize

```
A, A, A, A, A
B, B, B, B, B
C, C, C, C, C
D, D, D, D, D
E, E, E, E, E
F, F, F, F, F
G, G, G, G, G
```

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a random process that checks for dupes and reruns columns as needed.

```r
myfunc <- function(nrow = 7, ncol = 4, iters = 500) {
  m <- matrix("", nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)
  len <- seq_len(nrow)
  m[,1] <- sample(LETTERS[len])
  iter <- 0
  for (col in seq_len(ncol)[-1]) {
    iter <- iter + 1
    if (iter > iters) break
    m[,col] <- sample(LETTERS[len])
    while (any(m[,col] == m[,-col])) {
      iter <- iter + 1
      if (iter > iters) break
      m[,col] <- sample(LETTERS[len])
    }
  }
  attr(m, "iter") <- iter
  m
}

set.seed(42)
myfunc()
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "A"  "B"  "F"  "D" 
# [2,] "E"  "G"  "A"  "C" 
# [3,] "G"  "C"  "B"  "A" 
# [4,] "F"  "A"  "C"  "G" 
# [5,] "B"  "D"  "E"  "F" 
# [6,] "C"  "E"  "D"  "B" 
# [7,] "D"  "F"  "G"  "E" 
# attr(,"iter")
# [1] 69
```

I added the internal `iter` counting just so that we'd know how many times it took. And I added the `iters` limit so that it would not go on forever with ridiculous combinations; you'll know it hit the limit when one or more columns are empty strings `""`:

```r
myfunc(7,7)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,] "D"  "E"  "G"  "B"  "A"  "C"  "G" 
# [2,] "B"  "A"  "D"  "G"  "E"  "F"  "C" 
# [3,] "C"  "D"  "F"  "A"  "G"  "E"  "E" 
# [4,] "E"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "F"  "A"  "B" 
# [5,] "F"  "G"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "F" 
# [6,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "F"  "D"  "G"  "A" 
# [7,] "G"  "F"  "A"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D" 
# attr(,"iter")
# [1] 501
myfunc(7,7)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,] "D"  "E"  "C"  "F"  "G"  "B"  ""  
# [2,] "G"  "D"  "E"  "A"  "F"  "C"  ""  
# [3,] "F"  "A"  "B"  "G"  "D"  "A"  ""  
# [4,] "E"  "B"  "F"  "D"  "C"  "D"  ""  
# [5,] "A"  "C"  "G"  "B"  "E"  "E"  ""  
# [6,] "C"  "F"  "A"  "E"  "B"  "F"  ""  
# [7,] "B"  "G"  "D"  "C"  "A"  "G"  ""  
# attr(,"iter")
# [1] 502
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You may want to add a check, perhaps `nrow >= ncol`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a deterministic permutation, create the matrix and fill it in using the `row()` and `col()` functions.  For example,

```r
    rotated <- function(r, c, symbols = NULL) {
      num <- max(r, c)
      m <- matrix(NA, r, c)
      m <- (row(m) + col(m) - 2) %% num + 1 
      if (!is.null(symbols)) {
        m <- symbols[m]
        dim(m) <- c(r,c)
      }
      m
    }
    rotated(7, 4, LETTERS)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D" 
#> [2,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "E" 
#> [3,] "C"  "D"  "E"  "F" 
#> [4,] "D"  "E"  "F"  "G" 
#> [5,] "E"  "F"  "G"  "A" 
#> [6,] "F"  "G"  "A"  "B" 
#> [7,] "G"  "A"  "B"  "C"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want it randomized, permute rows and columns randomly:

```r
rotated(7, 4, LETTERS)[sample(7), sample(4)]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,] "B"  "D"  "C"  "A" 
#> [2,] "F"  "A"  "G"  "E" 
#> [3,] "E"  "G"  "F"  "D" 
#> [4,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "G" 
#> [5,] "G"  "B"  "A"  "F" 
#> [6,] "C"  "E"  "D"  "B" 
#> [7,] "D"  "F"  "E"  "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shifting approach you may realize like so.

```
mapply(function(x, y) x[(seq(x) + y - 1) %% nrow(m)], as.data.frame(m), 1:ncol(m))
#      V1  V2  V3  V4 
# [1,] "A" "B" "C" "D"
# [2,] "B" "C" "D" "E"
# [3,] "C" "D" "E" "F"
# [4,] "D" "E" "F" "A"
# [5,] "E" "F" "A" "B"
# [6,] "F" "A" "B" "C"
```

---

*Data:*

```
m <- structure(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), .Dim = c(7L, 4L))
```